How to fix GPIO pin number for sysfs on Raspberry Pi 5 new Linux kernel debian bookworm?
When I control GPIO pin on Raspberry Pi 5 debian bookworm, it doesn't work unless I add GPIOCHIP base address number to the pin number.
For example, if I want to export pin 20, I need to use
sudo sh -c "echo 591 > export"
adding GPIO4 base number 571 to it. How to fix the issue?

Does this answer your question? How do Linux GPIO numbers get their values?

I'm not sure how you expect the system to behave in order to consider it "fixed". And I'm not familiar with the RPi specifically but chips put their I/O all over the place and what pin an I/O goes to is up to the person doing board layout -- in essence, random. [ Just hard code the number for the GPIO you want to control in your setup function, and use meaningful names at the high-level (/sys) interface. ]
[ There is a program called gpio that is part of the obsolete wiringpi package here: https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/ ]
As @0andrly mentions in the comment, setting GPIOs via sysfs is deprecated. More information is available here, which also says that it is unlikely that this interface is going to be removed any time soon:
https://www.thegoodpenguin.co.uk/blog/stop-using-sys-class-gpio-its-deprecated/
I can't add more information than what is at that blog post, but in short it is recommended to use libgpiod, which comes with a C library and C++ and Python bindings. Userspace has the commands gpiodetect, gpioinfo, gpioget, gpioset, etc. The article explicitly mentions that one benefit of this is that unlike the /sys inteface, GPIO pin numbers won't change unexpectedly. However, you may need to program these values into the device tree explicitly. There are links to the relevant kernel documentation at the bottom of the article.
This article has another explanation, but also includes a sample program at the end that you may find helpful: https://www.ics.com/blog/gpio-programming-exploring-libgpiod-library
The article also claims to be part of a longer GPIO series but I can only find a link to Part 1 and it seems it dead-ends there. Regardless, Google reports a lot of Q&A on the RPi forums.

sysfs must not be used. It's very old and obsoleted interface for GPIOs. wiringpi seems a custom library that I do not recommend to use either. The libgpiod or ones based on it should be used for years already.

The reason is that I am using a linux_libnfc-nci library which uses sysfs. It exports GPIO pin 20 to use, and it was OK with previous kernel. When I upgraded to new kernel, I found out sysfs is no longer supported properly and GPIO pin number changes. That is why I am checking if there is fix to modify the pin number for sysfs

The short answer to your specific question here is no. The kernel assigns numbers based on when it finds the devices. New kernels will have new probe routines or different module configurations and things will be found in a different order. Even with the same kernel it /could/ change based on hardware timing. Compiling your own kernel with static code only (no modules) may help, but it doesn't seem like it can be guaranteed necessarily.
